# Project point onto plane along the direction of a given vector

Tags: projection-matrices, projection

I want to find a *non-orthogonal* projection matrix (3D). Basically, I want to project all points from one set onto a plane along the direction of a given vector. And I want to compute the matrix of that transformation.

Comment: What do you know about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a projection?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it. I can rotate whole system so my projection vector is orthogonal (for example (0, 0, 1)). And then its simple. X, Y coords stay the same and Z coord has to fit the plane equation ax + by + cz + d = 0.
If d = 0 (plane intersects point (0,0,0) (you can move your plane)) then its simple:
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\-a&-b&c\end{bmatrix}
matrix.
And after you can rotate system back.